# How would I say "fallen" in a Christian sense?

Tags: christianity, ecclesiastical-latin

Suppose I want to talk about "fallen angels": angels who (according to some Abrahamic sects) rebelled against God and were cast out of Heaven.

What would be the appropriate word for this? I'm not very familiar with Christian terminology in Latin.

Comment: Daemonium is undoubtedly the primary term to refer to fallen angels. Now for the sole adjective the choice is less obvious. I guess both casus and lapsus are good

Comment: @luchonacho The concept of fallen angels isn't universal within some of the major Abrahamic religions, which is why I use "sect" instead: for example, some sects of Judaism believe in fallen angels, while others don't.

Comment: Latin transliteration for nephilim? But that comes with baggage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say *angeli lapsi*, based on the general use of *lapsus* in Catholic theology.  There's no direct example in the Bible, I believe, but is supported by e.g., the Latin Catechism, which *inter alia* says:

> Satan seu Diabolus ceteraque demonia angeli sunt lapsi quia libere
>   renuerunt Deo Eiusque servire consilio. Eorum contra Deum optio
>   definitiva est. Hominem eorum rebellioni contra Deum sociare conantur.
>   [see http://www.vatican.va/archive/catechism_lt/p1s2c1p7_lt.htm ]

Answer (score 5):

The verb used in Luke 10:18 is (not surprisingly) ***cadere***: *Videbam Satanam sicut fulgor de cælo cadentem*.

Similarly Gal. 5:4: *a gratia excidistis* "ye are fallen from grace".