# Not fallen in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Would "Non Lapsus" be a good way of writing "Not Fallen" in Latin?

(Lapsus chosen because it refers to the Biblical Fall of Man)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Lapsus* seems like a good translation for "fallen"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7184/406); it just needs to be declined for the right gender and number (one man is *lapsus*, one woman is *lapsa*, and so on).

The obvious way to invert an participial adjective in Latin is the *in-* prefix; unfortunately, in this case, [*illapsus* has its own meaning already](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dillabor). So your *non lapsus* is the best alternative I can think of.

Comment: Oh God, Illapsus would've been amazing. Too bad I can't use it, and strange that it's meaning is itself falling and not 'not falling'. Thanks so much, Non Lapsus it is, or Numquam Lapsus

Comment: My understanding is that [*in-* could be used to negate a participial adjective, but a verbal participle would be negated with *non*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/7468/9) (basically the same pattern as for  *un-* vs. *not* in English).

Comment: @sumelic Right; I'll edit to clarify that

Comment: @Johan88 It's a strange historical accident in Latin! The PIE negation prefix (which shows up as *an-* in Greek and *un-* in English) ended up looking exactly the same as the preposition for "in/into" (*en* in Greek and *in* in English), so you sometimes have to check a dictionary to know which one is meant.

Comment: @Draconis fascinating. Thanks

Comment: @Draconis That accident led me to ask a follow-up question: [Are the two prefixes *in-* ever found with the same word?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11348/79)

Answer (score 3):

"The Fall of Man"? Well, if yourself is seeking doom-laden imagery, how about "(non) occasus"?

This masculine noun (gen. occasus), verb: occido, occidi, occasum [3], as well as "falling" incorporates the "setting-sun"--used by writers to project endings (good or bad); "end" in its own right; and, of course, "death"!

It also means "west". Given the state of the Western-World, at the moment (Brexit to the rise of fascism) there's plenty of (potential) "doom" in the air. But, guessing that contemporary politics is beyond the remit of your Q?

Remember Private Fraser in "Dad's Army"? "We're doomed!" Let's hope not.