# Can 'in-' mean both 'in' and 'no'?

Tags: example-request, prefix, ambiguity

The prefix *in-* can mean "in" or "into" or similar, as in *inire*.
It can also mean "non-" or "un-", as in *infelix*.
Both meanings of the prefix are attested, but I am not familiar with any case where both readings of *in-* are possible.
Is there a word with which both meanings are attested (or otherwise reasonably defensible)?

This question arises from [this earlier one](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11336/79) and especially comments to the answer by Draconis.
I am looking for something like *illapsus* meaning both "in-fallen" and "non-fallen".
I imagine participles, especially those that have become adjectives in their own right are a potential source of such ambiguous prefixes.

Comment: Of course it is not the case of the same prefix having two meanings. It is about two different IE preformatives merging in Latin.

Comment: @fdb I am aware, but that was somewhat irrelevant for the question. What matters here is that they look alike at the time of classical Latin so that the ambiguity arises.

Comment: Related: Sometimes people misinterpret words like *inflammable* ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is worth pointing out that native speakers of Latin were well aware of the ambiguity referred to by Joonas in his question (directional/locative prefix *IN*- vs. negative prefix *IN*-). For example, consider the ambiguity of *invocatus* ('called upon' and 'not called upon') that is comically exploited by Plautus in the following text (Pl. *Capt.* 1, 69ff.):

> Iuventus nomen indidit Scorto mihi,
>   eo quia **invocatus** soleo esse in convivio.
>   Scio absurde dictum hoc derisores dicere,
>   at ego aio recte. Nam scortum in convivio
>   sibi amator, talos quom iacit, scortum **invocat**.
>   Estne **invocatum** an non est? est planissume;
>   verum hercle vero nos parasiti planius,
>   quos numquam quisquam neque vocat neque **invocat**,
>   quasi mures semper edimus alienum cibum;

For relevant discussion of the ambiguity of *invocatus* involved in 'called upon' (directional IN- + *vocatus*) and 'not called upon' (negative IN- + *vocatus*), please read the following **note 1** contained in this [English translation](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:abo:phi,0119,005:1:1) (*The Comedies of Plautus*. Henry Thomas Riley. London: G. Bell and Sons, 1912).

> 1 **Because invocated**: "Invocatus." The following Note is extracted from Thornton's Translation of this Play:--"The reader's indulgence for the coinage of a new term (and perhaps not quite so much out of character from the mouth of a Parasite) is here requested in the use of the word 'invocated' in a sense, which it is owned, there is no authority for, but without it no way occurs to explain the poet's meaning--which, such as it is, and involved in such a pun, is all that can be aimed at. The word 'invocatus' means both 'called upon' and 'not called upon.' Ergasilus here quibbles upon it; for, though at entertainments he attends, as it is the common character of Parasites to do, without invitation, that is 'not called upon;' and as mistresses are 'called upon' that their names so invoked may make their lovers throw the dice with success; still, according to the double sense of the word, they may be compared to each other, as they are both, according to the Latin idiom, 'invocati.'"

---

NB I: A couple of ambiguous words like the ones commented on by Tom Cotton and cnread are: *oratio inscripta est* ((I) NEG *in*-: 'the speech is unwritten' and (II) DIR/LOC *in*-: 'the speech was inscribed/signed' (e.g., with the author's name)) & *inauratus* ((I) NEG *in-*: 'not ornamented with gold' or (II) DIR/LOC *in-*: perf. pass. participle of *inaurare* 'to cover with gold').

NB II: I think it is also interesting to point out that in Latin there are very few examples of co-appearance of the negative prefix *IN-* with the directional/locative *IN-*. For example, the three ones found in [Baldi (1989: 6)](https://www.persee.fr/doc/igram_0222-9838_1989_num_43_1_1971) are: *ininventibilis*, *ininvestigabilis*, and *ininvicem*. Cf. this [link](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/navigate.pl?lewisandshort.8) for a more complete list.

Comment: That Plautine pun is an excellent find! The double prefixed ones are interesting too; I can't recall seeing those before. The other findings are interesting too and answer my question, but I do somehow quite like the twist here.

Answer (score 7):

I'm inclined to agree that participles are a likely source, as you suggest.

An example that springs to mind is *innatus*. As the perfect participle of *innascor* it means 'having been born in', etc. A little surprisingly, as that of *innato* it would mean something like 'having been floated upon' (perhaps, for instance, *hydrargyrum innatum est ferro*, though I can't find a proper attestation, and Latin might better express this the other way round).

On the other hand there is *innatus*, used adjectivally by Tertullian — *Innatus deus; an non et innata et materia?* (Lib. adv. Hermogenem) — which appears to mean 'not born'.

There is also the pair *intego, intectum*, 'cover over' and *intectus*, used adjectivally for 'not covered'.

I imagine that a search for further (and maybe more convincing) instances could be tedious, but these may suffice to indicate that the two-readings possibility exists.

Answer (score 6):

The example that comes most immediately to my mind is *invisus*.

As the perfect passive participle of the verb *invideo*, it means 'looked at askance' (i.e., looked upon, but in a bad way), and it's regularly used, by extension, as an adjective meaning 'hateful' or 'unpopular.' Use of this adjective/participle is very common.

As the negative of perfect passive participle *visus*, from the verb *video*, it means 'unseen.' This is somewhat rarer, but *OLD* cites examples from such sources as Cato, *De agricultura* 141.2, Cicero, *De haruspicum responso* 57, and  Apuleius *Metamorphoses* 5.3.

Answer (score 4):

One more example that I have come across is *infectus, -a, -um,* which can be either the [negative of *factus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dinfectus1) (with the meaning "undone, not done, unfinished; impossible") or the [perfect passive participle of *inficio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dinfectus2) (with the meaning "stained, dyed, (dis)colored").

Comment: Nice pair! There appear to be many examples of Ablative absolutes with this verbal adjective. E.g., _infectis iis_ (Caes. _B. C._ 1, 33) is translated as "without having accomplished those things" (involving a syntactically null AGENT: cf. "without **PRO** having accomplished those things"). However, I was wondering if this Lat. adjectival passive would be better rendered as "without those things accomplished", i.e., as involving a RESULTATIVE reading of the participle, where there is NO **syntactic** agent involved (following Embick's (2004) famous tripartite classification of participles).

Comment: Ok, sumelic! Thanks! By the way, as a native speaker of English, could you tell me if it is possible in English to say the following **eventive** (i.e., "verbal") passive: "without those things having been accomplished (by someone)"? In any case, the prefix _in-_ gives an adjectival reading in Latin. To put in Embick's (2004) terms, only a **resultative** reading would be possible here (crucially, not an eventive/"verbal" one, i.e., the one that involves a (null or explicit) syntactic agent).

Comment: @Mitomino: "without those things having been accomplished by ___" seems weirdly phrased, but not very unacceptable to me. But I can't say whether it could take an eventive reading. As I mentioned recently in the comment about "un_ed by" constructions, I'm not sure that the presence of a "by" prepositional phrase referring to a semantic agent is perfectly correlated with the distinction between verbal (or eventive) vs. adjectival (or resultative) readings.

Comment: Ok, sumelic, many thanks for your helpful comment and judgement!