# What is the translation of "Cashless Society" into Classical Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation

The world seems to be moving this way, so how would Romans in the classic era have translated the phrase "cashless society". I am ignoring the fact that they didn't use paper money for simplicity.

My first thought was something like *Societas Penuniarum Sine Chartas*, or "a society that has money without paper", but I'm not sure that would really make any sense because it doesn't convey that the money is actually made of paper. I'm also probably didn't decline this correctly. :)

Comment: What meaning of "cash" are you going for here? "Physical objects representing currency"?

Comment: Yes, pretty much any kind of physical representation of currency. I guess it's a little different for the Romans because their currency actually had intrinsic value.

Comment: Combining some of the ideas in the answers below, you could possibly try the effect of *civitas post nummum*.

Answer (score 7):

The Romans had a word for hard cash, as opposed to money or wealth in general: **nummi**.

One could therefore say: **Civitas nummorum expers.**

I think it would not be lost on the Romans that this would not mean *sine opibus et divitiis*, and one could still transfer wealth somehow in such a society; after all, they did have bankers and kept books (*tabulae*).

Perhaps you could also say things like: *Sine nummis emere, obsonari* – shop (groceries) without cash, etc.

Answer (score 2):

When first introducing the concept in a Latin text, you probably need to explain what is meant.
Bear in mind that while *nummus* may principally refer to cash, I cannot think of a way to say "cashless" that would probably not mean "poor" to a Roman — or many other people.
Therefore context and explanation is needed to make the concept understandable, unlike with the established English word "cashless".
But once such explanation is made and you want to continue to refer to the idea in the text, a more succinct expression is needed.
With ambiguity dispelled by context, you can go for something compact and idiomatic.

I find the use of a privative adjective to be an idiomatic choice for this purpose.
Just like *exsanguis* and *exanimus* are deprived of blood and life, respectively, you could coin<sup>1</sup> the adjective *enummus* for something deprived of *nummus*.
(Before N the prefix should be *e-* rather than *ex-*.)
A similar but somewhat cumbersome alternative is *nummatus* ("furnished with money", an attested adjective) with a suitable prefix like *in-*.
I would go with ***civitas enumma*** or ***civitas innummata***.

There are different options for the prefix.
I chose *in-* to signify negation (it can refer to [both negation an "in"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11348/79)), and the prefix is used this way with adjectives and participles.
I think *e-* and *de-* could be possible, too.
Using *e(x)-* as prefix (in either *enumma* or *enummata*) seems to imply that there once was cash but it has been taken away, whereas *in-* only states that there is no cash.
I chose *in-* with *nummata* because the option with *e-* was already available with the more compact *enumma*.

---

<sup>1</sup> Only an hour after writing the answer do I realize how suitable the word "coin" is. This time the pun was entirely unintentional.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your proposal of _societas innummata_ for "cashless society". Do you mean _societas **ex**nummata_ instead?

Comment: @Mitomino I did mean *in-*, but it's not the only option (whence I wrote "a prefix like *in-*" rather than "the prefix *in-*"). I added a paragraph on the choice.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the **ambiguity** involved. I must say that the first reading I assigned to _innummata_ is the one similar to _nummata_, probably because of the existence of minimal pairs like _inauratus_ and _auratus_. Note that _inauratus_ is also ambiguous. Unlike _innummata_, note that _exnummata_ is **not** ambiguous.

Comment: @Mitomino I agree that *innummata* is ambiguous, but I actually disagree that *exnummata* isn't. I would read it as "moneyless" or "poor", but with suitable context and explanation I would find both prefixed versions of *nummata* reasonable for "cashless". I doubt there is an unambiguous Latin adjective for "cashless", but of course that need not stop endeavours to minimize ambiguity.

Comment: Presumably it would be *enummata*, as Latin does not seem to allow *xn*. Note that this would specifically mean a society that had once had coinage and had it taken away, rather than simply "a society lacking coinage".

Comment: @TKR Good points, thanks! Updated.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: A Roman may have interpreted "a cashless society" as a reference to the pre-money World of bartering. The noun "permutatio, onis (fem.)"  = "barter". Therefore expressions "negotiari sine pecunia" = "to trade without money" and (nominative-of-gerund) "negotiari est permutare" = "trading is bartering (swapping)" may have held more currency, in the Roman World. (That pun was intended.)

Comment: *I cannot think of a way to say "cashless" that would probably not mean "poor" to a Roman* — or to an English speaker a hundred years ago, then again.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Indeed! And even in today's English "cashless" might not be familiar to everyone in the sense used here. I would be interested to know if some living Latin circles have an established expression for this.

Comment: Maybe a less succinct phrase would add in the needed context? Something along the lines of "a society that pays without cash", or making some kind of adjective out of "cashless purchase".

Comment: @Adam I think the premise of my answer was not clear enough, so I added a first paragraph. I was specifically looking for something succinct for continued use, but it would need to be coupled with a more elaborate explanation as an introduction. Were you looking for that too? I assumed you were only after the more compact variant.